# Correct practice for using Bcrypt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, bcrypt, bcrypt-ruby

> [This guide](http://housewifehacker.com/bcrypt-with-rails.html) shows how to use Bcrypt with Rails, but it differs **significantly** in implementation from [this Rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html) on Bcrypt.

---

## Guide version

#### Set password

```
def password=(password)
  self.password_digest = BCrypt::Password.create(password)
end
```

#### Authenticate password

```
def is_password?(password)
  BCrypt::Password.new(self.password_digest) == password
end
```

But the documentation does the same thing using built in methods.

---

## Documentation version

#### Set password

Setting `user.password` or setting both `user.password` and `user.password_confirmation` values, then calling `user.save` will invoke some callbacks from Bcrypt which will take the password values and generate the digest and save that in the database.

```
user.password = 'mUc3m00RsqyRe' 
user.password_confirmation = 'mUc3m00RsqyRe' 
user.save
```

#### Authenticate password

The method `user.authenticate(password)` will return false or the instance variable of `user` depending on whether or not the password argument matches `user.password_digest`.

```
user.authenticate('notright')
user.authenticate('mUc3m00RsqyRe')
```

---

## Questions

- I had always used the documentation version, since I saw it first, but does the guide follow some better practice?
- Why does the guide rewrite the wheel? That seems very un-Railsy.
- Is this just a difference in versions of Bcrypt or Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is to use `has_secure_password` (the documented method) which was available since Rails 3. Maybe the guide was based on a practice prior to Rails 3?